# return from a linq where statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have the following link function

```
MyLinqToSQLTable.Where(x => x.objectID == paramObjectID).ToList();
```

I most of the time you can change a linq call to be several lines by adding curly brackets around the method body.  Like this:

```
MyLinqToSQLTable.Where(x =>
{ 
    x.objectID == paramObjectID;
}).ToList();
```

Problem is the implied return that was there when I just did a Boolean compare is now not done.  Return (x.objectID == paramObjectID); is not accepted either.

How do do this?  can I do this?

NOTE: I know that I can add another where clause if needed.  But I would still like to know the answer to this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first query is equivalent to this one:

```
MyLinqToSQLTable.Where(x =>
{ 
    return x.objectID == paramObjectID;
}).ToList();
```

You are missing the `return` keyword here. It's necessary when the lambda body is an explicit block rather than an expression.

The spec formally defines *lambda-expression* in grammar like:

> *lambda-expression*:
>       *anonymous-function-signature*   =>   *anonymous-function-body*
>
> *anonymous-function-body*:
>       *expression*
>       *block*

The former case (*expression*) applies when the body doesn't begin with a left curly brace. The latter case (*block*) is defined as a series of statements (just like a method body). Like other places in C#, expression statements in a block are restricted to declarations, assignments, function call, increment, and decrement. Merely applying operator `==` to a couple identifiers doesn't the expression a valid statement. The second issue is that when the return type of a method (anonymous or not) is not `void`, all code paths reaching the end of the block should return a value. Consequently, even if the body of your lambda was syntactically valid, without a return statement, your lambda would be convertible to `Action<T>`, and not `Func<T, bool>` that `Where` method expects.

---

#### Update:

> Problem is the implied return that was there when I just did a Boolean compare is now not done. Return (x.objectID == paramObjectID); is not accepted either.

Of course, the `x => { return x.objectID == paramObjectID; }` variant of your lambda expression is *only possible* when it's supposed to be converted to an **anonymous method**, not an **expression tree**.  That is, a lambda with a *block* body is not convertible to `Expression<T>`. That's why you can use it in LINQ to Objects (in which `Where` takes `Func<T, bool>`) but you can't use it in LINQ to SQL (in which `Where` takes `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`).

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a multi-line lambda can not be used in LINQ to SQL or EF because it is not convertible to an expression tree.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
MyLinqToSQLTable.Where(x =>  
{   
    return x.objectID == paramObjectID;  
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
MyLinqToSQLTable.Where(x =>  
{   
    return x.objectID == paramObjectID;  
}).ToList();  
or
MyLinqToSQLTable.Where(x =>  
{   
    return x.objectID == paramObjectID;  
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: There are already two other answers saying the same thing.  This answer is adding no value whatsoever.